# How to fix the TLS Server Name Indication issue under Windows XP on Nginx using a different IP

Tags: nginx, ip, ssl-certificate, sni

I have a server that is using two different domains with two different certificates.
Everithing work fine except IE8 on Windows XP because the TLS Server Name Indication is not supported there.
In order to fix this problem I want buy a dedicated IP for the second domain and set this IP on the nginx listen configuaration file.

The question is, it is possible set a dedicate IP on the listen nginx parameter?

Comment: If you have only a couple of sites sharing an IP, you could just buy a certificate with multiple alternative names. This works correctly on XP with IE.

Comment: I need a wildcard for one domain plus 2 subdomain for the other domain

Comment: Um, the answer is [yes](http://nginx.org/r/listen).

Comment: Setting the dns and the ip on the listen parameter the server is not responding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting a different IP on each domain fix the problem.

Comment: Isn't setting up a different IP for each domain exactly what SNI exists to help avoid having to do?

Comment: Yes, but it has limited browser support: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/configuring_https_servers.html#sni